# Why is CSSTransition not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a reusable modal component with transitions, but CSSTransition doesn't work, i have been trying for many ways but nothing works. Maybe is createPortal, or useContext.

I am interested in creating a single modal component for several pages, and only place the transition once so that it is reusable

Route

```
const App = () => {
    const initialState = useInicialState();
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={initialState}>
            <AdminProvider>
                    <Routes>
                            <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
                        <Route element={<Layout />}>
                            <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                            <Route exact path="/areas" element={<Areas />} />
                            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>} />
                        </Route>
                    </Routes>
            </AdminProvider>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Hook:

```
const useInicialState= ()=>{
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    return{
        openModal,
        setOpenModal
    }
}

export default useInicialState;
```

Context:

```
import React from "react";

const AppContext = React.createContext({});

export default AppContext;
```

Modal Component:

```
const Modal = ({children}) => {
    const {openModal, setOpenModal}= useContext(AppContext)
    const nodeRef = useRef(null);

    console.log(openModal)

    const handleClose = ()=>{
        setOpenModal(false)
    }

    return (
        ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <div className="modal-background">
                <CSSTransition
                    in={openModal}
                    timeout={500}
                    classNames="modal"
                    unmountOnExit
                    nodeRef={nodeRef}
                >
                <div className="modal" ref={nodeRef}>
                    <button onClick={handleClose} className="button-close">
                        x
                    </button>
                    {children}
                </div>
                </CSSTransition>
            </div>,
            document.getElementById('modal')
        )

    ); 
}

export default Modal
```

Page:

```
const Areas = () => {
    const [token] = useContext(AdminContext);
    const {openModal, setOpenModal} = useContext(AppContext);
    const [sectors, setSectors] = useState([]);

    const getSectors = async ()=>{
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
            },
        };
        const response = await fetch("/api/sector/list", requestOptions);
        if(!response.ok){
        }else{
            const data = await response.json();
            setSectors(data);
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getSectors();
    }, [])

    const handleModal= ()=>{
        setOpenModal(!openModal)
    }

    return (
        <>
            {openModal && (
                <Modal>
                    <p>esto es una prueba</p>
                </Modal>
            )}
            <button className="button-create" onClick={handleModal}>Crear área</button>
              <table className="styled-table">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Descripción</th>
                      <th>Modificar/borrar</th>
                      <th>Administrar personal</th>
                      <th>Administrar aspectos</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  {sectors.map((sector)=>(
                      <tr key={sector.sector_name}>
                          <td>{sector.sector_name}</td>
                          <td>{sector.sector_description}</td>
                          <td>
                              <img src={edit} alt="" />
                              <img src={garbage} alt="" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <img src={personal} alt="" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <img src={drop} alt="" />
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  ))}
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </>
    )
}

export default Areas;
```

and last Css:

```
.modal-background{
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top:100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.5);
}

.button-close{
    position: absolute;
    left:200px;
}

.modal{
    position:relative;
    background-color:white;
    margin:auto;
    margin-left:267px;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.modal-enter{
    opacity:0;
    transform:scale(0);
}

.modal-enter-active{
    opacity:1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms;
}

.modal-exit{
    opacity: 1;
}

.modal-exit-active{
    opacity:0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find myself the solution, thge problem was by the conditional for CSStransition.

```
{openModal && (
                <Modal>
                    <p>esto es una prueba</p>
                </Modal>
            )}
```

with out this condition work fine:

```
                <Modal>
                    <p>esto es una prueba</p>
                </Modal>
```